# condense many ul elements into one

Tags: jquery, html-lists

My html is generated like this:

```
 <div class="tags">
    <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Green</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>Blue</li>
        <li>Yellow</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Whats the best way to strip out the extra ul elements and condense into one. For example:

```
 <div class="tags">
    <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Green</li>
        <li>Blue</li>
        <li>Yellow</li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Prevent from generate the first way.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a clever(er) way to do it, but simple iteration ought to get you there:

```
$result = $('<ul></ul>');
$('ul').each(function() {
  $(this).children('li').appendTo($result);
});
$('.tags').empty().append($result);
```

​
fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yS3fg/)

Comment: +1. But you should be able to skip the `.detach()`, because `.appendTo()` will move existing elements if the new parent is a single element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.tags li').appendTo('.tags > ul:first-child');
$('.tags > ul:not(:first-child)').remove();
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UEVwU/)

Comment: +1. That's nice and neat. `$('.tags > ul:gt(0)').remove();` is even neater for the second line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div.tags').html($('<ul></ul>').html($('div.tags ul li')));
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/UtQJp/4/)

Answer (score 0):

heres a simple answer

```
var thisUL = $('ul').eq(0);
    $('li').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo(thisUL);
      $('ul').each(function() {
       var elem = $(this);
         if (elem.children().length == 0) {
          elem.remove();
         }
     });
   });
```

Comment: Nesting the `.each()` loops seems kind of inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tags ul:eq(0)' )  // targeting first ul
    .append( $('.tags ul:gt(0) li') )  // append all children of other ul
    .parent()  // jump to .tags
    .find('ul:gt(0)')  // target all ul accept first
    .remove(); ​// remove those ul​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**OR**

```
$('.tags').html($('<ul/>', {
    html: $('.tags ul li')
}))​;​
```